# realpath returns empty string

Tags: php, mediawiki, realpath

I use MediaWiki but there is an error. I found it in the files. There is line with this code:

```
$IP = realpath( '.' );
```

But $IP returns an empty string, so the path to the files in the system is not working. (for example if $IP would be `.` or `E:/path_to_wwwroot` it works). How can I solve the problem. Is it possible that my provider blocked access to realpath?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any joy with `./`? Shouldn't make a difference but might be worth a shot...

Comment: No:-( $IP is still empty. But for example basename works. But I don't use it, I want to know why I get this error. There might be more errors with realpath:-(

Comment: and also `realpath()` does not work on files that do not exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

> **Note:** The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise `realpath()` will return FALSE.

So your web server should have access also to pre-webroot directories.

Comment: Ah thanks, It needs read permissions on all directory in the wwwroot? Or also the files outside the wwwroot?

Comment: Wow, it solved the problem! Many thanks. I needed to change the read permission from my subdomain map. Thanks!!!

Comment: I ran into this when I was running the "portable" PHP+NGINX app WT-NMP and my sandboxed PHP app was referencing libraries outside the path I specified for open_basedir in php.ini.  I solved it by also adding my library path to open_basedir (using the ";" delimiter on Windows).

Comment: realpath on a file that does not exist also returns a blank

Answer (score 1):

I am currently experiencing this result when running PHP from command line, but not within an HTTP request. Got to be config or $_SERVER settings somewhere, will update if I find the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The path I was creating didn't exist, make always sure that it's well formed.

This is the path I was using:

```
realpath(MY_PATH . '../other_path');
```

Where `MY_PATH` didn't have a trailing `/`.